Error fetching orthologs:Error in `httr2::req_perform()`: ! HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
I have the following R code to download gene ortholgues using biomaRt. This code was working! However, I have problem now with the code. Does any one knows, what could be the reason?
library("biomaRt")

getOrthos = function(org_id1 = "hsa", org_id2 = "dre", ensVersion = 109){
    org.info = list("dre" = "drerio", "nfu" = "nfurzeri", "mmu" = "mmusculus", "hsa" = "hsapiens")              
    org1_ensembl <- useEnsembl(biomart = 'genes', dataset = paste0(org.info[[org_id1]],'_gene_ensembl'), version = ensVersion)
    org2_ensembl <- useEnsembl(biomart = 'genes', dataset = paste0(org.info[[org_id2]],'_gene_ensembl'), version = ensVersion)
    org1_genes = getBM(attributes = c('ensembl_gene_id', 'external_gene_name'), mart = org1_ensembl)
    org2_genes = getBM(attributes = c('ensembl_gene_id', 'external_gene_name'), mart = org2_ensembl)
    ensList = list("org1" = org1_genes, "org2" = org2_genes)
    
    org1TOorg2.orthos = getLDS(attributes=c("ensembl_gene_id","external_gene_name"),mart=org1_ensembl,attributesL=c("ensembl_gene_id","external_gene_name"), martL=org2_ensembl)
    colnames(org1TOorg2.orthos) = c(paste0(org_id1, "ENS"), paste0(org_id1, "SYM"), paste0(org_id2, "ENS"), paste0(org_id2, "SYM"))
    idx1 = org1TOorg2.orthos[,2] == ""
    org1TOorg2.orthos[idx1, 2] = org1TOorg2.orthos[idx1, 1]
    idx2 = org1TOorg2.orthos[,4] == ""
    org1TOorg2.orthos[idx2, 4] = org1TOorg2.orthos[idx2, 3]
    org1TOorg2.orthos$rwns = paste(org1TOorg2.orthos[,1], org1TOorg2.orthos[,2], org1TOorg2.orthos[,3], org1TOorg2.orthos[,4], sep = "qq")
    return(org1TOorg2.orthos)
}

the_orthos = getOrthos()

the error is as below:
Error fetching orthologs:Error in `httr2::req_perform()`:
! HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.

the problem is raised by this part:
org1TOorg2.orthos = getLDS(attributes=c("ensembl_gene_id","external_gene_name"),mart=org1_ensembl,attributesL=c("ensembl_gene_id","external_gene_name"), martL=org2_ensembl)
    colnames(org1TOorg2.orthos) = c(paste0(org_id1, "ENS"), paste0(org_id1, "SYM"), paste0(org_id2, "ENS"), paste0(org_id2, "SYM"))
    

